# Linking worksheets based on a pivot column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet linking issue. For example let the data in the work books look like this

Book1

> A     1    aaa
>
> B     2    bbb
>
> C     3    ccc

Now I link this sheet to another sheet by reference and it has same values as in here

Book 2

> A    1    aaa
>
> B    2    bbb
>
> C    3    ccc

Now if I add another column in Book 2 like below

Book 2

> A    1    aaa   10
>
> B    2    bbb   20
>
> C    3    ccc   30

Now if I link this new column back to Book1 it looks like below

Book 1

> A    1    aaa   10
>
> B    2    bbb   20
>
> C    3    ccc   30

But now if I sort column 1 in book 1 it doesn't sort the column4 because that is referenced to Book 2 which looks like below

Book 1

> C    3    ccc   10
>
> B    2    bbb   20
>
> A    1    aaa   30

But expected output is

Book 1

> C    3    ccc   30
>
> B    2    bbb   20
>
> A    1    aaa   10

But I want the sorting to happen on the new column that is added as well. A solution I could think of is to share a single sheet. But that doesn't serve my purpose so I need a linking which is sophisticated enough to sync across the books. Is there a pivot column based linking where the column1 in two books are taken as a reference when the manipulation happens on any sheet. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this isn't working for you, but I may be misinterpreting how you've set this up.
I've set up two workbooks, each with identical data for the first three columns, the fourth column in Book1 being linked to the same column in Book2.
[image: Formula View]

Here, you can see the formula view after I sorted on Column A.

This will not work properly if you had previously enabled Auto Filter *Before* putting in the links, since the Auto Filter will not have extended the filter range by itself. To fix this particular issue, simply disable and re enable the Auto Filter (You should see the drop-down icon on Column D after that).

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this type of "missorting" problem before. My solution was always to copy and paste the formulas in a different sheet as values.

Otherwise you could make column D dynamic through VLOOKUP and not reference hard cell numbers.

Comment: Agreed, this is a simple approach that works well, or you could change it to a vlookup but that would require a re-calc every sort.